# Help with Java errors,

Tags: java, bluej

All of this is compiled and run in bluej, so no main method is required, i am recieving many errors and i am new to java so i do not know how to fix them. Any help would be great appreciated.

This one has errors`import java.util.*;

public class LettingAgent{

```
private ArrayList<Property>myProperty;
private int propertyNo;


public LettingAgent(){
    myProperty = new ArrayList<Property>();
    propertyNo = 0;
}

public void addProperty(String newAddress, char newLocation, int newMonthlyRent, int newNoOfBedrooms){
    Property newProperty = new Property(newAddress, newLocation, newMonthlyRent, newNoOfBedrooms);
    myProperty.add(newProperty);
}


public void removeProperty(int propertyNo){
    if(propertyNo>myProperty.size() || propertyNo<0){
        System.out.println("Invalid Property Number!");

    }else{
        myProperty.remove(propertyNo);
        System.out.println("Property Successfully removed.");            
    }
}


public void addTenant(int propertyNo, String tenantName){ 
    if(propertyNo>myProperty.size() || propertyNo<0){
        System.out.println("Invalid Property Number!");          
    }else{
        myProperty.get(propertyNo);
        //Property.newTenant(tenantName);            
    }
}


public void removeTenant(int propertyNo){
    if( propertyNo<myProperty.size()){
        myProperty.get(propertyNo);
        //Property.removeTenant();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid Property Number!");
    }
}
public void searchProperty(String searchAddress){
    int propertyNumber = 0;     
    for(Property Property : myProperty){
        myProperty.get(propertyNumber);            
        if (myProperty.get(propertyNo).equals(searchAddress)){
            System.out.println("Property Details: "+ Property);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No Such Property.");
        }

        if(propertyNumber>myProperty.size()){
            System.out.println("No Such Property.");           
        }else{
            break;
        }           

    }

}
public void propertyList(Char location, int maxRent, int minBedrooms){

    for(Property Property : myProperty){
        if((Property.getLocation().equals(location))&& (Property.get(newMonthlyRent).equals(maxRent))&& (myProperty.get(newNoOfBedrooms).equals(minBedrooms))){
            System.out.println(propertyNo);
            Property.displayDetails();                            
        }else{
            System.out.println("Property Does Not Fit Search Criteria!");
        }        
    }                    
}
```

}

`

this is the associated class `//Property class
public class Property{
    //initialised variables
    private String address;
    private char location;
    private int monthlyRent;
    private int noOfBedrooms;
    private boolean occupied;
    private String tenantName;

```
//constructor, to create a new property
public Property( String newAddress, char newLocation,int newMonthlyRent, int newNoOfBedrooms){ 
    address = newAddress;
    location = newLocation;
    monthlyRent = newMonthlyRent;
    noOfBedrooms = newNoOfBedrooms;
    occupied = false;
    tenantName = "";
}

//method to return the address of created property
public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}
//method to return the location of created property    
public char getLocation(){
    return location;
}
//method to return the rent of created property    
public int getMonthlyRent(){
    return monthlyRent;
}
//method to return the number of bedrooms of created property   
public int getNoOfBedrooms(){
    return noOfBedrooms;
}
//method to return the occupied status of created property    
public boolean getOccupied(){
    return occupied;
}
//method to return the name of the tenant of created property    
public String getTenantName(){
    return tenantName;
}
//method to set a new monthly rent
public void newRentRate(int newMonthlyRent){
    monthlyRent = newMonthlyRent;
}
//method to set a new tenant, but only works if current property is empty
public void newTenant(String newTenant){
    if(occupied){
        System.out.println(" ERROR! Property is already occupied. ");
    }else{
        tenantName = newTenant;
        occupied = true;       
    }

}
//method used to remove tenant and reset the occupied status to false
public void removeTenant(){
    if(occupied){
        tenantName = " ";
        occupied = false;
    }else{
        System.out.println("ERROR! Property is already empty.  ");
    }
}
//method implements a switch statement to switch the char type in to a more understandable string type
// and also then displays the full property details.
public void displayDetails(){
    String fullLocation;
    switch(location){
        case 'n': case 'N': fullLocation = " North London"; break;
        case 's': case 'S': fullLocation = " South London"; break;
        case 'e': case 'E': fullLocation = " East London"; break;
        case 'w': case 'W': fullLocation = " West London"; break;
            default: fullLocation = " unknown";
    }

    System.out.println("Address :" + address);
    System.out.println("Location :" + fullLocation);
    System.out.println("Monthly Rent : " + monthlyRent);
    System.out.println("Number of bedrooms : " + noOfBedrooms);
    System.out.println("Occupied Status : " + occupied);

    if(occupied){
        System.out.println("Tenants Name : " + tenantName);
    }else{
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

}
```

}
`

Comment: Do you mind posting the errors that you are getting?  Saying you're getting errors is a pretty broad statement.

Comment: If you give the errors, we may point out the problem.

Comment: I am getting errors within the addTenant(), and removeTenant() methods, i am not sure really how to add or remove attributes from an object within an array list,

Comment: also in the final method i recieve this error message, char cannot be dereferenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Property` does not have a method `get()` defined.

Change `Property.get(newMonthlyRent).equals(` to `Property.getMonthlyRent().equals(`

Also, it seems that you are mixing `Property` a **single property** with the ArrayList `myProperty` which holds a **list of all the properties**

The `get()` method on the ArrayList will return the single Property instance, so in your `addTenant()` method, use `myProperty.get(propertyNo).newTenant(tenantName);`

---

UPDATE

`Property.getLocation()` returns a `char` not a `String`. A `char` doesn't have an `equals()` method.

Change `Property.getLocation().equals(location)` to `Property.getLocation() == location`

Comment: thankyou so much, i am still getting the error char cannot be dereferenced in the final method on the if statement

Comment: apologese last thing on the same line is says now, cannot find symbol - variable newNoOfBedrooms, i dont understand this is the exactly the same as it was previously defined

Comment: change `myProperty.get(newNoOfBedrooms).equals(minBedrooms)` to `Property.getNoOfBedrooms() == minBedrooms`. please read the first 3 paragraphs of my answer to understand why.

Comment: i would just like to say i love you